# Dynamically filter and resize context menu c# while keeping its gravity to bottom

Tags: c#, filter, resize, contextmenu, gravity

I have a system tray context menu with 26 items and an additional `ToolStripTextBox` menu item. When the user enters text to the filter textbox it continuously filters the menu items as the user types and hides categories on the fly by setting the `ToolStripMenuItem` `Visible property` to `false`.

It's working!

The issue is that when it gets filtered, the height of the context menu gets shorter from the bottom towards the top. The origin point for the menu is the upper right corner, causing it to shrink upwards. Since it is a system tray related context menu, I expect it to shrink downwards (bottom gravity).

How to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure if there is a "proper" built-in method to do this...

In the mean-time, here's a hack that changes the Bounds() of the ContextMenuStrip whenever the size changes.  It simply shifts the ContextMenuStrip down/up by however much the height changed.  I've wired up the Opened() and SizeChanged() events of my ContextMenuStrip and store the last Bounds() in the "lastBounds" variable at class level:

```
    private Rectangle lastBounds;

    private void contextMenuStrip1_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lastBounds = contextMenuStrip1.Bounds;
    }

    private void contextMenuStrip1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rc = contextMenuStrip1.Bounds;
        int diff = lastBounds.Height - rc.Height;
        if (diff > 0)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(rc.X, rc.Y + diff), rc.Size);
            lastBounds = contextMenuStrip1.Bounds;
        }
        else
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(rc.X, rc.Y - diff), rc.Size);
            lastBounds = contextMenuStrip1.Bounds;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats a smart solution, although that's partially works for me, the issue is when I continually changing the text in the filter component the size of the context menu is continually changing, when appending text -> shorter and when deleting text -> higher.  After the first filter the diff size doesn't represent any more the "right" diff, and the context menu shifted to a random location.

Comment: Ah...your description only talked about **shrinking**, so I only took that into account.  I'll see if I can modify it to handle both shrinking and growing.  An alternative solution would be to turn OFF AutoSize for the ContextMenuStrip so that it stays the same size when items are removed.  Not sure if that's an option for you.

Comment: I added an ELSE block to the SizeChanged() handler to shift the ContextMenuStrip() back UP when it grows.